# Retrieve sorted data based on one numeric column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like attached image in SQL server.

[image: Sql table]

I am trying to retrieve sorted data based on `SUM(freight)` column. For this i have used the below query.

```sql
SELECT ShipCountry
FROM CountryDetails
GROUP BY ShipCountry
ORDER BY SUM(freight) ASC
```

When i run this i am getting result like below.

[image: SQL result]

If i run the below query i am getting result like below. It's fine.

```sql
SELECT ShipCountry, ShipCity
FROM CountryDetails
GROUP BY ShipCountry, ShipCity
ORDER BY SUM(Freight), ShipCity ASC
```

[image]

Instead of this i need a result like below. In order by clause `SUM(Freight)` should consider only `ShipCountry`. It should not consider both `ShipCountry` and `ShipCity`. My Expected result is

[image: Tableau image]

How to achieve this result through SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a query like below

```
select 
  ShipCountry,
  ShipCity
from
(
Select 
   ShipCountry, 
   ShipCity, 
   SUM(Freight) OVER( Partition by ShipCountry order by ShipCountry) NetCountry,
   SUM(Freight) OVER( Partition by ShipCountry,ShipCity order by ShipCountry) NetCity

 from 
   CountryDetails 
) T
Order by NetCountry asc,ShipCity asc
```

**<kbd>[Live Demo](http://rextester.com/DOD1273)</kbd>**

Comment: Yes. It returns the result like i expected. One more doubts is if i run the below query i have got result with redundant data.

Select ShipCountry from CountryDetails Order by SUM(Freight) Over(Partition by ShipCountry)

if i add group by clause i am getting error message. 

Select ShipCountry from CountryDetails group by shipcountry Order by SUM(Freight) Over(Partition by ShipCountry)

is this possible to get the same without getting redundant data?

Answer (score 0):

I think `CUBE` or `ROLLUP` will help you to attain the result. However please find the query below that I created. I just created the query from the model you shared. I can not guarantee on the performance. Also please omit the first and last columns.

```
;

WITH CTE_ShipDetails1
AS (
    SELECT ShipCountry
        , MIN(ShipCity) ShipCity
        , SUM(Freight) NetCity
        , 0 RowNum
    FROM CountryDetails
    GROUP BY ShipCountry
    )
, CTE_ShipDetails2
AS
(
SELECT CTE1.ShipCountry ShipCountry1
        , NULL ShipCountry
        , CountryDetails.ShipCity
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY CTE1.ShipCountry
                , CTE1.ShipCity
            ) RowNum
        , SUM(Freight) OVER(PARTITION BY CountryDetails.ShipCountry, CountryDetails.ShipCity)  NetCity
    FROM CountryDetails
        , CTE_ShipDetails1 CTE1
    WHERE CTE1.ShipCountry = CountryDetails.ShipCountry
        AND CTE1.ShipCity <> CountryDetails.ShipCity
)       
SELECT DISTINCT ShipCountry1, ShipCountry
    , ShipCity, NetCity, MIN(RowNum) RowNum
FROM
(
SELECT TOP 250000 ShipCountry ShipCountry1, ShipCountry
    , ShipCity, NetCity, RowNum
FROM CTE_ShipDetails1 CTE1 UNION
SELECT TOP 250000 ShipCountry1, ShipCountry
    , ShipCity, NetCity, RowNum
FROM CTE_ShipDetails2 CTE2 

) AS a  GROUP BY ShipCountry1, ShipCountry
    , ShipCity, NetCity
ORDER BY ShipCountry1 ASC
    , RowNum ASC

    ;
```